# Find examples of $f$ such that $f'$ is a probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $f$ be a probability density function with a continuous derivative on $[1,+\infty)$. I know that the conditions for a function to be probability density is as follows

(a) $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

(b) $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx=1$

Now I want to find examples of $f$ such that $f'$ is a probability density function. Is there exist any way to do this?

Comment: If your question is "I want some function $f$ such that $f'$ is a PDF" then any [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) will do. If your question is "I want a PDF $f$ such that $f'$ is also a PDF" then in general this is not true, but maybe you can cook up some simple example involving a uniform distribution or something.

Comment: I mean that both of $f$ and $f'$ are PDF.

Comment: They should be on the same "support" or it is not necessarily?

Answer (score 3):

Does this function $f$ (in the picture) fit the bill?

[image: the function f]

The formula of $f$ is

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}      
  x+3 \text{ when } x \in [-3, -2] \\  
  1 \text{ when } x \in (-2, -\frac{1}{2}] \\  
  0 \text{ when } x<-3 \text{ or } x>-\frac{1}{2}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Notice: the derivative of $f$ is continuous on $[1, +\infty)$ but not at $-3$ or $-2$.

[image: the derivative of f]

I don't put any Dirac deltas in the derivative when $f$ jumps (is this OK?).

Comment: Sorry, I could not see the pictures, would you indicate them with another way?